# Managing large excel files with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote a small C# procedure that compares two columns that belong to two different Excel worksheets. Each of these columns contains about 23.000 cells. For each element of the first column, the procedure checks if the element's value exists in the second column, if it does not exist it removes the row from the first worksheet.
The problem is that this procedure is very slow: it takes about 10 seconds to scan the second column for a matching value, so it would take about 10 * 23.000 seconds = 63 hours for the program to execute.

Is there a faster way to do this in C#?

Comment: Are you currently doing this from within Excel? There are many ways to do something like this. For starters, it would help to show the code you have written and give some details. This will still probably be too broad a question for SO, but as the question currently stands, it assuredly is.

Comment: @pstrjds: If you have data in an excel spreadsheet then serializing that data out and then back in wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: @pstrjds I updated the post: it is currently a C# procedure. Tomorrow I'll post the code.

Comment: @Guvante - I agree, that was the main reason for asking "Are you currently doing this from within Excel", but if it is already being exported and worked on in C# then I would answer in that direction.

Comment: deleting rows or cells has a performance hit, try to avoid that by setting the values in another column (note: don't copy/ paste, that's much more intense than setting the value). Also, set "Calculation" to manual at the app level, and disable application "screen updating".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to potentially solve this.  You said that you have around 23,000 rows of GUIDs so you should be able to load a `HashSet` with all the GUIDs from column 2.  Then you can just process column1, taking each element that you find in the HashSet.

```
var column2 = new HashSet<Guid>(); // Load this set with the data from column2

// Now you can just use a simple LINQ query to create a new column1
var column1Result = column1.Where(x => column2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Now you will have a list of GUIDs that are your new column1.  Just replace the original column1 with the new one and save the file.

Testing this on my machine, including time to populate two lists and a set with 100,000 GUIDs (where my test column1 had 50,000 matching and 50,000 non-matching), the whole thing took approximately 0.15 seconds.

**Edit - based on your comment**
With your situation as you described it, I would parse worksheet 2 to get the GUIDS and put all of those in the `HashSet`.  Then I would just walk down column1 of worksheet 2 and check for containment in the `HashSet` and delete as necessary.

Comment: I can't just replace the original column1 with the new one, since the worksheet does not contain only one column, but 5. What I can do is to scan the first worksheet, and delete the rows that are not contained in the list that contains the other worksheet's GUIDs. If I understood well hashSets, doing so will be a lot faster than scanning also the second worksheet. I will try this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if the values in the column is double type, then you can sort them. In each loop of searching, start from last loops last location and stop the searching when reach a number that's larger than what you are look for.

For example, you want to look for [2,4,7] in array [1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]. For the first loop, you want to look for number 2, so your search range is [1,3]. you stopped at 3 because 3 is larger than 2. Then for next search, you start with 3 and end at 4, since you found it.

Comment: The column type is Guid. I will try the method that you suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no doubt a million different ways to do this. With Excel there may be particular hang-ups that you want to check. Others have mentioned Delete being a slow function but also make sure you aren't creating/disposing of objects every time you are running the check. Keep all objects and just change the variables you need to. You may also consider multithreading and processing each row on a different thread. Don't try this unless you are confident in your multi-threading skills...

Try this for a simple sort-based solution to shorten parse times --

1. Sort both row A and B.
2. Store the value in the middle of B (Value of cell B.Count / 2)
3. Iterate through A - checking first if value is in top half or bottom half of B then searching through that half of the column only.

*Make sure to break processing after the value is found assuming your list is already distinct.